# Using ansible to grep then format the output

Tags: grep, ansible, xdebug

I am new to Ansible and would like to know how to achieve the following:

I have a large number of servers.  And on each of them I would like to run a grep command, then I want the output to be consolidated.

On each server, I want to run

```
 egrep -i 'abc' /etc/fstab
```

then i am looking for an output like below:

```
hostname1:  abd.........
hostname1:  ......abc...
hostname2:  ....abc.....
hostname3:  .abc........
```

Based on my research online, my playbook should look something like this:

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: search abc filesystem
    shell: egrep -i 'abc' /etc/fstab
    register: result

  - debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'result') | map(attribute='stdout_lines') }}"
    run_once: yes

  - name: Copy content
    local_action: copy content={{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'result') | map(attribute='stdout') | list }} dest=/home/result.txt
    run_once: yes
```

However, I cannot get the output to look like what I would like and the `grep` command does not seem to pick up `abc` on all servers.

Would appreciate if someone can explain what is the right way of doing this.

Comment: (1) Please correct `abd` in the first line and indent `msg` properly. (2) What does it have to do with [tag:xdebug]? (3) Please consider asking why "*grep command does not seem to pick up `abc` on all servers*" on SuperUser or Unix.SE -- I can't see how it fits this question and there's no data to answer that.

Comment: The data you are working on (`result`) does not contain host information. Refer to the answer under the duplicate question how to iterate in Jinja2 over hosts. You just need to add a second loop inside over `hostvars[host].result.stdout_lines`.